# How to fix latin character (e.g. ç, é) incorrectly displayed in emacs ess-buffer?

Tags: character-encoding, ess

When I read a file into R, and the file contain characters like  "ç" or "é" (latin characters) in a string, the ess-buffer shows meaninless (to me) numbers. For example, the string "ações" is displayed "a\307\325es". Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems file coding system was not detected properly. To open a file with a specific coding system in Emacs use:

```
C-x RET c coding-system RET C-x C-f filename RET
```

Where `coding-system` should be the one used by R.